# Como actualizar el estado de un componente hijo desde un componete padre mediante props

Tags: reactjs

Solicito la ayuda en Stackoverflow ya que no encuentro cómo dar solución a mi problema en React.

EL problema es el siguiente:

1. Al hacer click en el boton "aumentar" de mi componente Hijo se va aumentendo un contador 1,2,3,4
2. Luego al hacer click en el boton "siguiente" de mi componente Padre intento reiniciar el contador de mi Hijo pasandole por props a mi hijo la constante 1.
3. Necesito que al hacer nuevamente click sobre mi boton "siguiente" del componente padre el contador de mi componente hijo se reinicie en 1 y comience nuevamente el conteo 1,2,3,4,5 pero no me esta funcionado ya que se me muestra: 4,5,6,7.

Puede alguien gentilmente ayudarme. gracias deantemano.

```
    function Padre() { const [zoomer,setZoomer] = useState(0) const funcionA = (e) =>{ 
    setZoomer(1) } return (
    <Hijo zoomer={zoomer}>  <button id="siguiente" onClick={funcionA} /> ); } export default Padre;


    class Hijo extends Component { constructor(props){ super(props) this.state ={ zoomer: 
    props.zoomer } } aumentar = () =>{ this.setState({ zoomer: this.state.zoomer+1 }) } render() { 
   return (
   <div>
   <button onClick={this.aumentar}>aumentar</button>
   </div>

  ); } }
```

Comment: hola , he tratado de ayudarte a formatear el código; si deseas arreglarlo mas ya te puses las comillas que debes usar ...

Comment: Wao Arcanis mil gracias, no podia por nada del mundo formatear el codigo

Comment: tendras alguna idea para resolver el problema que planteo arriba

Comment: hay vas poco a poco aprendiendo no te preocupes por eso que para eso estamos en la comunidad.

Comment: no se mucho de typescript XD

Comment: tranquilo gracias de todas formas, realmentre el probelma es de React

Answer (score 0):

Es una pregunta muy interesante.

> Lo recomendable es diseñar la app ReactJS de tal forma que, el dueño del estado sea el componente `Padre`.

Intentar **actualizar/modificar/reiniciar** el estado desde `props` es un [**antipatrón**](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-erasing-state-when-props-change).

Ahora bien, hay formas de hacerlo, como se describe en la [documentación](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-erasing-state-when-props-change).

Una forma es pasando un `key` dinámico, cada vez que se quiera pasar una `prop` la cual, como en este caso de uso, va a **actualizar/modificar/reiniciar** el estado del componente `Hijo`.

Esto es solo una propuesta:

```
function Padre() { 
  const [zoomer,setZoomer] = useState(1);
  const [uKey,setuKey] = useState(0);
 
  const funcionA = (e) => { 
    let uid = 'id'+Math.floor(Math.random() * performance.now());
    setZoomer(1);
    setuKey(uid); 
  } 
  return (
      <>
      <Hijo zoomer={zoomer} key={uKey} />  
      <button id="siguiente" onClick={funcionA}>siguiente</button> 
      </>
      ) 
  };
```

Si se pasa un `key` único en cada devolución al componente `Hijo`, ReactJS creará una nueva instancia del mismo:

```
class Hijo extends Component { 
      constructor(props){ 
        super(props) 
        this.state = { 
          //aqui ya toma el valor proveniente de props, pues es nueva instancia
          zoomer: this.props.zoomer 
        } 
      } 
     
      aumentar = () => { 
        this.setState({ zoomer: this.state.zoomer+1 }) 
      } 
      render() { 
        return (
          <div>
          <button onClick={this.aumentar}>aumentar</button>
          </div>

          ); 
      } 
  }
```

Se puede ver un ejemplo mas completo en la [doc de reactJS](https://codesandbox.io/s/6v1znlxyxn).

---

Demo modificaciónes al código del OP:

```js
function Padre() { 
      const [zoomer,setZoomer] = React.useState(1);
      const [uKey,setuKey] = React.useState(0);
     
      const funcionA = (e) => { 
        let uid = 'id' + Math.floor(Math.random() * performance.now());
        setZoomer(1);
        setuKey(uid); 
      } 
      return (
          <div>
          <Hijo zoomer={zoomer} key={uKey} />  
          <button id="siguiente" onClick={funcionA}>siguiente</button> 
          </div>
          ) 
  }; 
      
  class Hijo extends React.Component { 
      constructor(props){ 
        super(props) 
        this.state = { 
          zoomer: this.props.zoomer 
        } 
      } 
     
      aumentar = () => { 
        this.setState({ zoomer: this.state.zoomer+1 }) 
      } 
      render() { 
        console.log("zoomer hijo:",this.state.zoomer);
        return (
          <div>
          <button onClick={this.aumentar}>aumentar</button>
          </div>

          ); 
      } 
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<Padre/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

---

Demo refactor Padre dueño  del estado:

```js
function Padre() { 
  const [zoomer,setZoomer] = React.useState(1);
 
  const funcionA = (e) => { 
    setZoomer(1); 
  } 

  function aumentar(){
    setZoomer(zoomer + 1);
  }

  return (
      <div>
      <Hijo zoomer={zoomer} handler={aumentar}></Hijo>
      <button id="siguiente" onClick={funcionA}>siguiente</button> 
      </div>
      ) 
  }; 

  function Hijo(props){
    return (
      <div>
      <p>{props.zoomer}</p>
      <button onClick={props.handler}>aumentar</button>
      </div>
    ); 
  }
  
  ReactDOM.render(<Padre/>, document.getElementById('root'))
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js" crossorigin ></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js" crossorigin ></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: En principio deseo agradecerte estimado amigo (no se tu nombre), he probado lo que me has aconsejado y todo ha salido de maravillas, me ha funcionado, mil gracias nuevamente por tu explicacion detallada y por el ejemplo, Dios te bendiga. Lo ultimo que si desearia saber solamente es que pasa con las instancias del hijo creadas cada vez que paso una nueva key, hay alguna forma de ir eliminado estas instancias o no debo preocuparme por esto ?

Comment: Después de dar un vistazo, no parece haber problemas con la nueva instancia mas alla de dar 20 o 30 clicks en el botón aumentar y reiniciar el contador varias veces, se comporta de forma esperada, sus métodos internos se acumulan en la memoria del explorador. Sin embargo, hay que tomar en cuenta que el equipo de React menciona que es un antipatrón y puede presentar [problemas de diferente tipo](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-erasing-state-when-props-change).

Comment: Me tome la libertad de hacer un refactor a tu código, puedes ver el demo; aquí el dueño del estado es el componente `Padre`, dejando al componente `Hijo` como componente stateless/presentational. Se respeta la misma funcionalidad.

Comment: Muchas gracias G.4 por la nueva propuesta, aunque para mi requerimiento me quedo con la primera solucion ya que tengo la necesidad de que el contador este en el hijo. Ahora solo necesito si eres tan amable me indiques como asignarte una puntuacion por tus respuestas, te lo pregunto ya que soy nuevo en stackoverflow y no se donde ni como evaluarte.

Comment: [Marca la respuesta como aceptada](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers): haz clic en la marca al lado de la respuesta (debajo del contador de puntos a favor o en contra); al hacer clic, cambiará de gris a verde. Saludos